# Netflix Desktop nor Pipelight are working?

Tags: wine, netflix, pipelight, netflix-desktop

I was formerly an Arch user, but with Ubuntu's Netflix-Desktop I figured it might be easier to get Netflix running. So I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Arch.

I was wrong, it was not easier. Both installed correctly. Netflix gave me the operating system requirement screen, so I installed a User Agent Switcher. Then, it proceeded but said I needed silverlight. So pipelight did not work. I resorted to Netflix Desktop.

I followed the guide step by step with no displayed errors. But after installing Netflix Desktop, wine asked me to install two things. I allowed it. After it was done, Netflix Desktop wouldn't open. However one question ( [Netflix desktop doesn't launch when I click on it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334236/netflix-desktop-doesnt-launch-when-i-click-on-it) ) led me to entering

```
netflix-desktop --showdebug
```

this gave me

```
################################################################################
# OpenGL Diagnostics                                                           #
################################################################################
Direct Rendering: Yes
OpenGL Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945G 
OpenGL Version: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
GLX Version: 1.4
################################################################################
# Firefox                                                                      #
################################################################################
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/solas/.wine-browser/drive_c/browser-profile/pluginreg.dat’:              No such file or directory
/usr/bin/wine-browser: 1: eval: -no-remote: not found
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and took a look into `/usr/bin/wine-browser`, which is a shell program. The `-no-remote` complaint is coming from this line:

```
eval ${FIREFOX} -no-remote -profile "${FIREFOX_PROFILE}" "${URL}" 2>>${OUTPUT} &
```

You don't have Firefox installed. Earlier in the script, `$FIREFOX` is set to the output of `which firefox` with no error checking.

You can also run with `--no-pipelight` and it will use a wine-installed version of Firefox. In this mode I had some trouble with alt-tab behavior.